# How to solve ? sign at the end of paragraph when i used substr function for hindi text

Tags: php, function

when i used substr function for limited text but i have some problem. At the end of the paragraph show ? mark sign .

```
 $article_desc = substr($row_posts['article_desc'],0,500);
```

Comment: Can you add some example text so people can try this out?

Comment: <?php

$text = "चैम्पियंस ट्रॉफी के अपने पहले मैच में भारत ने पाकिस्तान को 124 रन से हरा दिया। बारिश से प्रभावित 
मैच में टॉस हारकर पहले बैटिंग करने उतरी टीम इंडिया ने 48 ओवर्स में 3 विकेट के नुकसान पर 319 रन बनाए। डकवर्थ 
लुईस मैथड ";

$article_desc = substr($text,0,502);

echo "$article_desc";

?>

Comment: output-                                                                                                                             चैम्पियंस ट्रॉफी के अपने पहले मैच में भारत ने पाकिस्तान को 124 रन से हरा दिया। बारिश से प्रभावित मैच में टॉस हारकर पहले बैटिंग करने उतरी टीम इंडिया ने 48 ओवर्स में 3 विकेट के नुकसान पर 319 रन बनाए। ड�

Comment: how to remove ? sign end of the paragraph

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it with

```
$article_desc = mb_substr($text,0,502);
```

and it gives

```
 चैम्पियंस ट्रॉफी के अपने पहले मैच में भारत ने पाकिस्तान को 124 रन से हरा दिया। बारिश से प्रभावित मैच में टॉस हारकर पहले बैटिंग करने उतरी टीम इंडिया ने 48 ओवर्स में 3 विकेट के नुकसान पर 319 रन बनाए। डकवर्थ लुईस मैथड
```

I think the issue is that substr doesn't work well with certain character sets, mb_ is the multi_byte safe version of substr.

Comment: please give me a example of mb_is

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but there are a set of mb_ functions, look at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php which will give loads of details.

Comment: @sam Good to hear it, you may need to use more of the multi byte functions when using Hindi text, so keep that in mind.  Would be grateful if you would accept this as the correct answer.